# Sending an array as part of a PUT method in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, put

I am currently developing an app for Windows Phone 8 in C# that makes use of Quizlet.com's API, an online flashcard website.

One of the API calls documented in their API reference to edit a flashcard set requires you to send an array of terms and definitions through a PUT method.

Presumably do this you would have to use `HttpWebRequest` rather than `WebClient`, as the latter is too simple and doesn't support PUT requests to my knowledge. I cannot, however, seem to understand how you could send an **entire array as part of a PUT request**.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how one would do this? I'm sorry I don't have source code to attach, but it's probably not necessary as this is a more general question.

Thanks in advance!

---

This is the code I'm currently using that is not working:

```
RestClient Edit = new RestClient("https://api.quizlet.com");
            RestRequest EditRequest = new RestRequest();
            EditRequest.AddParameter("term_ids[]", ID);
            EditRequest.AddParameter("terms[]", Terms);
            EditRequest.AddParameter("definitions[]", Definitions);
            EditRequest.AddParameter("title", item.Title);
            EditRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + CurrentLogin.AccessToken);
            EditRequest.AddHeader("Host", "api.quizlet.com");
            EditRequest.Resource = "2.0/sets/" + item.Id;
            EditRequest.Method= Method.PUT;
            Edit.ExecuteAsync(EditRequest, Response =>
            {
                FinalizeUpdate(Response);
            });
```

I declare my arrays as such:

```
    int[] ID;
    string[] Terms;
    string[] Definitions;
```

And I add data to my arrays as such (TermsList is an ObservableCollection):

```
        foreach(Term i in TermsList)
        {
            ID[Counter] = i.Id;
            Terms[Counter] = i.Name;
            Definitions[Counter] = i.Definition;
            Counter++;
        }
```

Below is the class definition for Term:

```
public class Term
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("term")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("definition")]
    public string Definition { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of the API ?

Comment: https://quizlet.com/api/2.0/docs/sets/#edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is RESTful, so I would recommend using an external library if possible, such as RestSharp.

From what I can see in online examples of other APIs, the way to send an array is simply to send the same parameter again with a different value.

i.e., using RestSharp's API you would do :

```
client.AddParameter("imageData[]", data1);
client.AddParameter("imageData[]", data2);
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to work, after I execute the request I get an error message from Quizlet saying I need to send at least two terms for each set, meaning the arrays were probably not sent properly. Am I instead supposed to format the array into some type of string, or should sending just the array itself work?

Comment: please show more of your code, I'm sure we can solve this if you do :-)

Comment: I just updated my original post with the code I'm currently using, could you take a look at it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: OK, guessing what "Terms" is (if you could post its definition, it would be better) - an array, this is not what I meant to do. You should iterate over it (foreach (var term in Terms) { .AddParameter("terms[]", term }). I believe what happens now is that its sending the ToString of that Terms object, which is probably some generic "Array.Object"

Comment: Alright, your edit coincides with what I write. You should iterate over your array. In additions, the terms array is an array of string. You shouldn't put complete JSON objects there. You should iterate over it, and put ONLY the term strings. Same for ids.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however, if you look closely I don't actually store entire JSON objects in my arrays. I instead store the objects within an ObservableCollection and then pull the specific parameters from there and put them into my arrays. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: My bad about the observable collection. I'm glad I helped at least.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem, this is code that finally got the PUT method to work:

```
            RestClient Edit = new RestClient("https://api.quizlet.com");
            RestRequest EditRequest = new RestRequest();

            foreach (var i in ID) 
            { 
                EditRequest.AddParameter("term_ids[]", i);
            } 
            foreach (var i in Terms)
            {
                EditRequest.AddParameter("terms[]", i);
            }
            foreach(var i in Definitions)
            {
                EditRequest.AddParameter("definitions[]", i);
            }

            EditRequest.AddParameter("title", item.Title);
            EditRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + CurrentLogin.AccessToken);
            EditRequest.AddHeader("Host", "api.quizlet.com");
            EditRequest.Resource = "2.0/sets/" + item.Id;
            EditRequest.Method= Method.PUT;
            Edit.ExecuteAsync(EditRequest, Response =>
            {
                FinalizeUpdate(Response);
            });
```

I hope this helps!